# How to warp the later frame to previous frame using optical flow image

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, opticalflow

I just have two images,one is the current frame,the other is the optical flow image which calculated by other manners.

The current frame is:
[image]

The optical flow image is:
[image]

My question is how to calculate the previous frame using the two images?

I have saw one solution,just using bilinear interpolation to warp current frame to last frame with optical flow image.But I didn't know how to do it.

So,could someone give me some advice or ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See also: [OpenCV warping image based on calcOpticalFlowFarneback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17459584/365102).

Answer (score 13):

You are looking for the opencv function [remap](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=map#cv2.remap). If you have the current image (`currImg`) and the optical flow mat (`flow`) than you can predict the previous image by first inverting the optical flow and then apply the function `remap`. In python the code will be as follows:

```
import cv2
h, w = flow.shape[:2]
flow = -flow
flow[:,:,0] += np.arange(w)
flow[:,:,1] += np.arange(h)[:,np.newaxis]
prevImg = cv2.remap(curImg, flow, None, cv.INTER_LINEAR)
```

Comment: Hello! Just curious: what's the point of inverting the optical flow here? If the flow is from prev image to current image, according to cv2.remap's formula, dst(x,y) =  src(map_x(x,y),map_y(x,y)). Is your code basically adding the grid to the flow?

Comment: Optical flow is usually competed from previous to current image. If you want to get the previous from the current image, you have to invert the flow direction