# Convection of an image using optical flow

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I have two images (frame1 and frame2) and I am able to calculate u,v using opencv:

```
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs,next, 0.5, 1, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1, 0)
```

I want to translate frame1 using this u,v to quantify the quality of the difference using various optical flow methods. I intend to extrapolate using these u,v.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: What is `(u,v)`?

Comment: Oh, do you mean each point has a `(u,v)` vector attached to it?

Comment: yes. I guess this could solve my issue but I am not able to convert the equivalent of Point in python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459584/opencv-warping-image-based-on-calcopticalflowfarneback

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to compute a simple translation is to average the flow:

```
avg_u = np.mean(flow[:, :, 0])
avg_v = np.mean(flow[:, :, 1])
```

This gives the vector `(avg_u, avg_v)` needed to translate.

---

**Regarding your comments**, it seems you want to move every pixel `(x,y)` to the location specified by its flow vector `(u(x,y), v(x,y))`.

First, generate a Cartesian grid:

```
height, width = flow.shape[0, 1]
R2 = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(np.arange(width), np.arange(height)))
```

Then, the desired mapping is simply the addition of this grid with the flow:

```
pixel_map = R2 + flow
```

Finally, perform a [`cv2.remap`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#remap):

```
new_frame = cv2.remap(prev_frame, pixel_map)
```

Comment: Interestingly, using R2+ flow is giving worse results than R2-flow with large margin. I am using it for extrapolation.