# Create frame from previous frame and Optical Flow

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow

I have a video and I need to simulate frames using Optical Flow; i.e. having a frame and the Optical Flow that represents the pixel translation for the next frame simulate this following resulting frame.

I am using Python and OpenCV as follows:

1. Generate flow between two consecutive grayscale frames

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev_gray, gray, None, pyr_scale = 0.5, levels = 5, winsize = 11, iterations = 5, poly_n = 5, poly_sigma = 1.1, flags = 0)
```

This is the flow between first and second frames:

[image: First frame optical flow]

This is the following (target frame):

[image: Original second frame]

2. Now, I want to use the first frame and the Optical Flow to generate the second frame estimation. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535091/convection-of-an-image-using-optical-flow)

```
height = flow.shape[0]
width = flow.shape[1]
R2 = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(np.arange(width), np.arange(height)))
pixel_map = R2 + flow
```

```
prev = original_frames[0].astype("float32")
pixel_map = pixel_map.astype("float32")
new_frame = cv2.remap(prev, pixel_map, None, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

The resulting image is:

[image: Resulting frame]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was solved slightly updating the code as follows:

```
h = flow.shape[0]
w = flow.shape[1]
flow[:,:,0] += np.arange(w)
flow[:,:,1] += np.arange(h)[:,np.newaxis]

new_frame = cv2.remap(original_frame, flow, None, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```